# Error creating terminal: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying

Tags: gnome-terminal, dbus

Why can't I open the `gnome-terminal` (version `3.18.3-1ubuntu1` on Ubuntu 16.04) any more?

[image]

The error message is this:

```
Error creating terminal: 
Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
```

Comment: Please check if there are still runnung processes of gnome-terminal. If so kill them and then try to start it again.

Comment: Please tell us the version of your gnome-terminal (output of: `apt-cache policy gnome-terminal'). Paste the information and your Ubuntu version in the original post.

Comment: No, I have reboot many times.

Comment: So you can open a new gnome-terminal window using the Unity launcher/Dash, but you can't start a new instance from inside the terminal, right?

Comment: No, I can't. This is not the gnome-terminal, it is UXTerm.

Comment: The gnome-terminal can be opened by other users, except mine.

Comment: It happens to my PC and laptop after the recent update.

Comment: I have found where the problem is, it is caused by the gcin input method.

Comment: @JulianLai You should write a solution ere